# How to send via my iphone application a planned emails and without launching the email application?

Tags: iphone, email, launching

I know how to send email from my application by launching the iPhone Mail application, then return to my app. But I have two concerns:

1 / My first concern is how my application can send emails without opening the mail application?

So I will inform the user that the email has been sent successfully or failure on failure of transmission.

2 / My second concern is to make sending mail programmed (in scheduled task) as in the case of UILocalNotification.

I have not found a solution, I try to avoid knowing the solution that uses open source classes for sending mail via SMTP, because I want my application uses the configuration of the iphone and mail ask the user to configure where the mail is not configured.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send mail from your app using MFMailComposeViewController.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `MailCore` or similar alternatives.
2. You cannot do that with your app in the background. It's not the same as `UILocalNotification` as it requires user's approval before the app can do anything about that notification.